# How does jQuery .fadeTo() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm curious how `.fadeTo()` fades an element? Does it use an inline style of opacity to do this?

And if it does not use css opacity, then how would you control css opacity using jQuery or javascript?

This question is referring to all of the following:

```
.fadeTo()
.fadeIn()
.fadeOut()
```

Comment: Even though browsers implement opacity differently, all browsers implement it. So it's a matter of detecting and implmenting the correct type for the browser/version, not a matter of it being inline/block level attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the jQuery source - CSS opacity.

```
fadeTo: function( speed, to, easing, callback ) {
    return this.filter(":hidden").css("opacity", 0).show().end()
                .animate({opacity: to}, speed, easing, callback);
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I am asking is that I'm using a plugin, and that plugin changes the opacity of an element. I have watched the source in firebug and I see the opacity changing in the inline style of that element. I'm curious if there is a way I can control that same element's opacity?

Comment: Yep. `$('selector').css('opacity', 50);` will set an element to 50% opacity. If you want to animate it to a value, you can use `$('selector').animate({opacity: 50}), 'slow');` to do that, see http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for more options.

Answer (score 6):

It does use CSS opacity!

Check out the source code here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

And search for `fadeTo`.

You will see (as of today, anyway):

```
fadeTo: function( speed, to, easing, callback ) {
    return this.filter(":hidden").css("opacity", 0).show().end()
        .animate({opacity: to}, speed, easing, callback);
},
```

Comment: Thanks. Curious, if there is a plugin that is controlling the opacity of an element, how can I use a function to act upon that elements opacity in the same way?

Comment: If you search in the source again for "animate:" you'll see the animate method the fade uses. The first parameter for this is "prop" - that's "property", so in our case "opacity". You can all it directly if you wish to.

Comment: The opacity is part of the style property of the DOM element and this can be operated on by jQuery or by the plugin or by plain old DOM manipulation through raw JavaScript.  They all affect ultimately the same thing even if used together.  Are you asking how to control opacity through a separate plugin, or from scratch?  Sorry if I am not understanding the question.